Camel Azure Event Hubs - Message Not Receiving
My code :
from("azure-eventhubs:? connectionString=RAW(<CONNECTION_STRING>)&credentialType=CONNECTION_  STRING&blobContainerName=BLOCB&blobAccountName=ACNAME&blobAccessKey=RAW(<<KEY>>)").process(exchange -> { String body = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
exchange.getIn().setHeader(EventHubsConstants.PARTITION_ID, 4);
System.out.println(body);
System.out.println("Message received successfully"); 
}).to("mock:result");


Be aware that you've posted sensitive information, including the access keys to your resources.   I've redacted, but the content is still available in history.  I would strongly advise that you roll your secrets immediately.

@Dharanidharan.T Can you check this MS DOC to receive messages from Azure Event Hub using connection string in Java?

Here I have reproduced the above issue with the required results.

I have used springboot framework for my camel application please check the receiving code.

MessageReceiver.java:
package camel.sample;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class MessageReceiver {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageReceiver.class);

    public void onMessage(String message) {
        logger.info("Received: {}", message);
    }

}

EventhubsRouteBuilder.java:
package camel.sample;

import org.apache.camel.builder.endpoint.EndpointRouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class EventhubsRouteBuilder extends EndpointRouteBuilder {

    @Value("${namespaceName}")
    private String namespaceName;

    @Value("${eventhubsName}")
    private String eventhubsName;

    @Autowired
    private MessageReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        from(timer("tick")
            .period(1000))
            .setBody(constant("Event Test"))
            .to(azureEventhubs(namespaceName + "/" + eventhubsName));

        from(azureEventhubs(namespaceName + "/" + eventhubsName))
            .bean(receiver)
            .log("The content is ${body}");
    }

}

Pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-example-spring-boot-azure</artifactId>
    <version>4.6.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>camel-example-spring-boot-azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
  <name>Camel SB Examples :: Azure Event Hubs</name>
  <description>An example showing how to work with Camel, Azure Event Hubs and Spring Boot</description>

  <properties>
    <category>Cloud</category>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Camel -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.springboot</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-azure-eventhubs-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-endpointdsl</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot-version}</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>repackage</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>


This route consumes messages from Azure Event Hubs and processes them, printing the message body to the console.


Recieved messages:

Reference:

camel-example-spring-boot-azure-eventhubs

